# Why does filter(flights, dest == c("IAH", "HOU")) produce a non-empty set?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I'm doing Exercise 5.2.4, Question 1 (2), in R for Data Science (https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#exercises-7), and accidentally wrote
`filter(flights, dest == c("IAH", "HOU"))` instead of `filter(flights, dest %in% c("IAH", "HOU")).`

I'm puzzled as to why my wrong code still produced 4,655 rows of obs? dest is a 1-dimensional variable, and `c("IAH", "HOU")` is a 1x2 vector. The 4,655 rows filtered seem to have dest equal to IAH or HOU, but only a subset of the 9,313 observations correctly filtered by `filter(flights, dest %in% c("IAH", "HOU"))`.

Code:

```
library("nycflights13")
library("tidyverse")
filter(flights, dest %in% c("IAH", "HOU"))
filter(flights, dest == c("IAH", "HOU"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R it's doing `flights$dest == c("IAH", "HOU")` and as these vectors are of different length, it's repeating your second vector the amount of times needed to be the same length as dest (see example of this behavoir if you paste vectors of different lenghts `paste(c(1:4), c("a", "b"))` ). 
Because of this, it's a 50/50 probability if when flight$dest actually is IAH, if the repeating second vector is on IAH or HOU to make the condition true and the same for when flight$dest is actually HOU. This is why empirically you got essentially half of the subset you were looking to get without your typo.